# How to define embedded properties in Loopback Model definition JSON file

Tags: json, loopbackjs, strongloop

According to Loopback Documentation, we can define embedded document properties programmatically such as:

```
var UserModel = {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    address: {
      street: String,
      city: String,
      state: String,
      zipCode: String
    },
    ...
}
```

*or*

```
var AddressModel = {
    street: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zipCode: String
};
var Address = ds.define('Address', AddressModel);
var UserModel = {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    address: 'Address',
    ...
}
// or address: Address
var User = ds.define('User', UserModel);
```

My question is whether we can also do it in the Model definition JSON file.

I found that you can create an other JSON file and then reference it directly in the module definition file as type.
ex.

```
{
"name": "Address",
"base": "Model",
"strict": true,
"idInjection": false,
"properties": {
  "id": false,
  "street": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "city": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "state": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "zipCode": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "country": {
    "type": "string"
  }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {},
"acls": [],
"methods": {}
}
```

and then reference it the original JSON definition of User such as

```
address:{
    type:'Address'
}
```

But I haven't found how to directly declare it inside one JSON definition without requiring a different file. (Same as programmatically first example)

I have tried

```
address:{
    street: 'string',
    city: 'string'
    ...
}
```

but with no result. Data does not get verified and it considers it as an **any type** property that can save anything

Answer (score 2):

Actually It seems that you can define sub document properties in Model Definition JSON file the way I mentioned like:

```
address:{
    street: 'string',
    city: 'string'
    ...
}
```

The problem is that this anonymous model is defined with no strict option, which defaults it to false, so any other property is also allowed...

I have also created an issue about this being fixed somehow in order to easily create subdocs without creating a separate separate definition JSON file.

[Github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/923)